# Mongo query based on string length inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo db structure that looks like this and I would like to retrieve all the entries where blood type length is bigger than 2.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23"),
    "contact" : {
        "firstName" : "Mark",
        "lastName" : "Doe",
        "parentsBloodType" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "AB+",
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "A+",
            }, 
        ],
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-31T07:13:11.278Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T09:59:41.611Z")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dba898fdsw54c132c104a23"),
    "contact" : {
        "firstName" : "Helen",
        "lastName" : "Fly",
        "parentsBloodType" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "O-",
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "AB-",
            }, 
        ],
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-31T08:13:11.278Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T09:59:41.611Z")
}
```

I tried the following query:

`db.users.find({"contact.parentsBloodType.type" : {$exists:true}, "$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$contact.parentsBloodType.type" }, 2 ] } })`

But I got this error:

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$strLenCP requires a string argument, found: array",
    "code" : 34471,
    "codeName" : "Location34471"
}
```

How can I correctly do this?

Comment: Do you want the whole document  in the output _or_ just the array elements that match the "contact.parentsBloodType.type"'s length>2?

Comment: I want the whole document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will match documents where the `type` field length is 3 or greater:

```
db.users.find( { "contact.parentsBloodType.type" : { $exists: true }, "contact.parentsBloodType.type": { $regex: /.{3,}/ } } )
```

NOTES:
The regular expression `.{3,}` means any character (specified by dot (`.`)  metacharacter) with length of 3 or greater (specified by `{3,}`).  Also, see MongoDB's [$regex query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html).

Comment: Does this query works if `contact.parentsBloodType` is an array of 2 `[{type: "a"}, {type: "abc"}]`? Wouldn't the document be returned?

Comment: It works, because the "abc" has a string length of 3 (which is greater than 2).